# sylius product image display issue, imagine open function is throwing errror

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have uploaded image for a product but not able to display it. It's throwing below error.

Unable to create image for path `ae/98/a4afdbab7fbc99ee6ab40b9763d7.jpeg` and filter `sylius_shop_product_original`. The message was

> "Unable to open image /var/www/html/qoneco/web/media/image/ae/98/a4afdbab7fbc99ee6ab40b9763d7.jpeg"
>   Exceptions 2

I have tried folder permission changes but that didn't work.

getting the error in this line.

```
$image = $this->imagine->open($binary->getPath());
```

Comment: code and error formatting